# Binding IСommand к произвольному событию произвольного компонента

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Все найденные мною примеры демонстрируют привязку `IСommand` к компонентам, содержащим свойство `Command:`

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Width="100" Height="100" Content="GO!"/>
```

Как привязать `ICommand` к произвольному событию компонента WPF, не содержащего свойство `Command`, и передать этой команде параметр? Например - повесить команду `MyFunnyCommand` на событие `RowEditEnding` компонента `DataGrid` и передать ей `DataGridRow.Item`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь у вас несколько путей.

Во-первых, есть примочки Blend. Подключив библиотеку System.Windows.Interactivity, вы сможете писать такой код:

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding ButtonMouseDownCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Foo}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Во-вторых, вы можете воспользоваться нормальной MVVM-библиотекой. Например, подключив библиотеку Caliburn.Micro, вы сможете писать такой код:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="ButtonClick"/>

<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action ButtonMouseDown($dataContext, 'Foo')]"/>

<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ButtonMouseDown">
                <cal:Parameter Value="$dataContext"/>
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding Foo}"/>
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Причём будут использоваться не команды, а методы.

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант помог!